# How do I prevent methods from being overwritten and assigned a different type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class-method

I want to protect all class methods and prevent them from being overwritten, e.g. `Object.assign(dog, { bark: true});`.  Someone said that for this reason you should not use class methods in Typescript because unlike simple functions and methods, class methods are overwritable.

```
class Animal {
  eingezahltkaptial: number[]=[1,2,3];

  move(distanceInMeters: number = 0) {
    console.log(`Animal moved ${distanceInMeters}m.`);
  }
   hello(): void {
      console.log(`Animal moved m.`);
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  bark(): void {
    console.log("Woof! Woof!");
  }
}

const dog = new Dog();
Object.assign(dog, { bark: true});
dog.bark();

[ERR]: "Executed JavaScript Failed:" 
[ERR]: dog.bark is not a function
```

Comment: About everything in JavaScript is overwritable, you just shouldn't do it. What are you trying to achieve, just get a typescript compile error? A runtime error on the `Object.assign` line? An object that is totally unaffected by the `Object.assign` line and still can have its `.bark()` method invoked afterwards? Something else?

Comment: Not sure what you're really after. `Object.assign` does _not_ modify methods/properties to be readonly, it _overrides_ equally named methods/properties. Therefor, the  error is 100% correct, because the `Object.assign` line _overrides_ `.bark` to a `Boolean` property which isn't a function.